# Problems With Websocket Server in C

Tags: javascript, c, nginx, websocket, server

I need to use NGINX as a WebSocket Proxy, and I've been able to run this [tutorial](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) without any problem. In this case, a simple WebSocket application is done using ws and Node.js. However, I need to substitute the code in javascript (server.js) with an application developed in C.

To do so, I've tried with the last example shown in this [tutorial](http://www.binarytides.com/socket-programming-c-linux-tutorial/), which is very simple and easy to understand.

However, using the same port and configuration as in server.js, when running the compiled C code, it seems that the communication is not properly established. In this case, when I run wscat in the client's terminal, it seems it is waiting for something since the word 'connected' is never seen, but the communication is not finished either (this is why I say it seems it is waiting for something; in other cases, if I try with a different port, for instance, the communication is closed and it appears a sentence as 'error: unexpected server response').

On the other hand, on the server side, I can see there is a new connection. I suspect that the answer from the server is not arriving at the client, but I don't know why. Nginx is properly configured since the example done in javascript works properly, and I'm using the same ports in both javascript and C (in server.js I have: 'wss = new WebSocketServer({port: 8010});' and in server.c: 'server.sin_port = htons( 8010 );'    from my point of view it should work...)

I've tried with other examples in C with a similar behavior. Does anyone know which may be the cause for this? Do you recommend other particular C codes for WebSocket servers?

Comment: In this case what's the motivation behind using pure C? Node.js can use FFI to load in C libraries if you need to use C for a portion of your code.

Comment: @tadman that's what he wants to use. Why question it?

Comment: @MustacheMoses There's an absurd number of Websocket-type servers for Node.js, you can throw a rock and hit six, but very few for C, that's why. I mention that because in the question having a JavaScript server is mentioned, so a partial conversion would be easier if that's the case.

Comment: @tadman Yes, I've had experience with the overabundance of websocket servers for node. The OP probably wanted to use C for performance.

Comment: @MustacheMoses That's why FFI + a C library is pretty nice. You get all the C you want, but you're not stuck using it for every single thing, even when it's not a good fit.

Comment: @tadman makes sense.

Comment: @tadman - the inverse is also true. It's quite easy to add JavaScript bindings (or Ruby, or PHP or...) to any C application you're writing - making it easy to extend any C application using scripting languages. I admit that the V8 JavaScript bindings require C++ (brrr...), but it's not that hard to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is that there's a very marked difference between *websockets* and sockets. Sockets are more low level network interfaces whereas websockets run on a web server of some kind.

I would recommend using a *websocket* library for C. :) [Here's](https://libwebsockets.org/) one I found after doing a quick google search. The documentation for said library can be found [here](https://libwebsockets.org/lws-api-doc-master/html/index.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you all for the clarification and the solution.

Answer (score 5):

The answer given by @MustacheMoses is very much to the point (I upvoted) - there's a huge difference between sockets and Websockets.

**Websockets** is a protocol that starts with an HTTP "upgrade" request and continues with a multiplexed message exchange protocol using a specific data packaging scheme.

**Sockets** refer to the lower level communication channels (i.e., Stream Sockets, such as TCP/IP sockets or Unix Sockets, or even Raw Sockets).

I would also point out that, much like node.js, websocket libraries / servers in C come in different flavors.

**Some libraries provide an almost Web Framework approach (for example, [kore.io](https://kore.io) or my own [facil.io micro-framework](http://facil.io)) and others are more narrow in scope**.

Much like node.js packages / servers (which are often written in C or C++), they all differ in performance and features (I would test this before I commit to a specific approach).

As @tadman rightfully pointed out, **it might be better to stick with your existing code base and add any C libraries you need using FFI**.

It's somewhat rare for high level services, such as web applications, to be authored using a lower level language.

The inverse is also true, it's often less desirable to author the lower level web server using a higher level language.

This is just my humble opinion, but consider that I'm writing this even though I'm the author of a websocket application framework written in C. When the time comes to write an actual production Websocket app, I often prefer to use facil.io as a Ruby C extension and write the app in Ruby (unless Ruby isn't available).